# Using cat as a conversion tool in Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, cat, file-conversion, busybox

I'm working on an embedded Linux 2.6 and I'm trying to get a shell script to be able to read text files regardless of their formatting (UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO*, any EOL format). I'm mostly restricted to Busybox applications, but I can use some lightwight open source code if it presents a good solution.

Now, I know that a completely universal solution might be impossible, but while studying the problem I noticed that cat seems to print the file contents correctly almost regardless of formatting. For exaple if I use a file with UCS-2LE formatting, the output looks like this:

```
# less test.txt
H@e@l@l@o@ @W@o@r@l@d@
# cat test.txt
Hello World
```

Now, I thought I would use cat to get most of the cases solved. But when I tried this:

```
cat test.txt > test2.txt
```

The formatting was still the same in test2.txt.

So the question is: can I somehow store cat output in a file? Not the original file contents, but what cat is actually showing me? Or some other tool? The only way I managed to do it was copy the output of cat with a mouse and copy it into a file, but that is not a feasable solution since I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

`iconv` is the standard linux tool for converting between character sets. Setting ucs-2le as the input format and ascii as the output should do the trick.

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv for more info. It's part of the GNU C library.

Comment: I am aware of iconv, but the problem there is that I need to know the original formatting. And in this case I don't always know it. The reason I'm interested in cat is that it seems to be able to display file contents correctly even without any knowledge of the formatting, and I'd like something like that.

Comment: Ah, okay, tricky. Will the `file` command help? That should be able to identify the type of text.

Comment: I might be able to do something by combining file and iconv, but the problem there is that at least one format displays as unknown-8bit or something like that. The frustrating thing here is that cat is showing me exactly what I want, but I am unable to store it in any automatic way.

Comment: Hmm - are you sure cat is doing it correctly and not just ignoring unprintable characters?

Comment: `cat`, by design (with no command line options), simply copies the command line files, in order, to stdout, without modification. Many shell scripts depend on this behavior. I cannot explain why, in your test, it seems to be changing formatting.

Comment: What you see might be a lie, a side effect.